# Why does a redirect from a local IP address assume localhost?

Tags: linux, browser, java, lan, redirection

I am developing a web application on my desktop and it is running on port 80. I am able to access the application from my laptop connected to the LAN by entering my desktop's LAN IP address 192.168.1.8. Now, my application sends a redirect after login, but my laptop assumes the final address is localhost/login. If I manually type in the IP address and URI for any page, it shows that I am logged in, so it works as expected. So, why does the redirect assume localhost?

Both of my machines are linux-based. The laptop being Chrome OS. I am running nginx which proxies non-static file requests to jetty on port 8080.

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 locahost
192.168.1.8 desktop
$ hostname
desktop
```

The redirect is sent from Jetty, with a `HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect()`

TL;DR:

```
Laptop: Request http://192.168.1.8/login
Desktop: Respond with redirect to /index
Laptop: Redirect request to http://localhost/index

Requesting http://desktop/login doesn't work.
```

Comment: Check your hosts file ?

Comment: How did you implement the redirect? Let us see config code, if possible.

Comment: @Tobias: What do you want to know? I don't know what else to provide.

Comment: Sorry, hitting Enter for a linebreak: Not such a good idea on StackExchange. Edited it in.

Comment: I added some information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is... nothing anywhere that implicitly redirects to `localhost`. Something within the framework or application is explicitly doing it.

Answer (score 0):

When connecting to any local interface address, the connection is done from 127.0.0.1 (the local loopback address).   This doesn't require a redirect. The name of this address is localhost, as you will find in /etc/hosts.  Many applications will check other local interfaces for a name and use that in preference to localhost.

Comment: My *application* requires a redirect. I don't understand why, when my server sends a redirect response, the redirect contains localhost instead of the IP address that made the initial request.

Comment: The incoming connection from localhost likely arrives on the localhost address.  If you don't rewrite the address in your redirect, it will be redirected on the same address. Redirect to `https://192.168.1.8/login` instead of just `/login`.

Comment: That doesn't really solve my problem, though. This application will eventually be deployed elsewhere, so I can't hardcode an IP address in the redirect.

Comment: Use the hostname from the incoming request.  This will work wherever you deploy, and will handle a deployment with multiple name.

Answer (score 0):

Jetty is prefacing every relative URL with its root domain (in Apache, it's called "Server Name", don't know about Jetty), I suppose: Hence the "localhost". So you need to replace the "localhost" with something that makes sense for both computerss:

You could make a domain like "example.com" your webroot in Jetty and define it as your webroot and add it to the laptop's hosts file.

Comment: Thanks Tobias, I think you have tipped me in the right direction. I turned off the proxy through nginx and things are working correctly by directly making requests to jetty. Now I'll just need to configure the proxy correctly. Thanks again.

Comment: @Jeremy: This indicates that Jetty or the app isn't correctly accommodating the `X-Forwarded-For` header generated by the proxy.